# Error formatting USB flash (Read-only file system)

Tags: formatting, readonly, usb-flash-drive

Can anyone help me with formatting USB ?

**The problem:**

Error formatting volume:

```
Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sda1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sda1: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Hello @Andrei. I don't think you're going to get a good answer to this question in stackoverflow... I would suggest you try asking or searching in Server Fault (I'm not sure but I think it's the right place). Also, it sounds like it may be a common error, have you tried searching elsewhere already? (don't hate me if you already have, it's hard not to sound passive-agressive)

Comment: On closer inspection, you seem to be using Ubuntu. You could also try askubuntu.com, you're sure to find help there.